# Incorrect output mismatch

Tags: c

I tried to simulate what the first line of code does but I am getting an logic error where it says that COMPARE_SCORE = 0.00, It should either chose between match or mismatch neither of which are 0.

Why is it printing 0?

```
#define COMPARE_SCORE (kA == wildcard || kB == wildcard) ? 0 : (kA == kB) ? match : mismatch

int main()
{
    int kA = 5;
    int kB = 6;
    int wildcard = 5;
    double match = 3.3;
    double mismatch = -1.1;
    
    printf("Value of COMPARE_SCORE = %f", COMPARE_SCORE);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(kA == wildcard || kB == wildcard)` is true because `kA == wildcard` is true, so the result is `0`.

Comment: I strongly recommend that if you use nested ternaries that you add parentheses to make sure that the grouping matches your expectations.

Comment: Also, whenever you use a macro to return an expression, you should surround it with `()` to prevent operator precedence problems when it's inside another expression.

Comment: If you want to return `0` only when both `kA` and `kB` match the wildcard you should use `&&` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following pair of parenthesis in your ternary macro:

```
#define COMPARE_SCORE **(**(kA == wildcard || kB == wildcard**)** ? 0 : (kA == kB)) ? match : mismatch
```